# RSpec fails when using custom validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

I am using such kind of validation in my rails 3.1 project.

```rb
validates_presence_of :sales_price
validates_presence_of :retail_price
validates_numericality_of :sales_price, :greater_than => 0,
                          :allow_blank => true
validates_numericality_of :retail_price, :greater_than => 0,
                          :allow_blank => true

validate :sales_price_less_than_retail

def sales_price_less_than_retail
  if sales_price >= retail_price
    errors.add(:sales_price, "must be less than retail price.")
  end
end
```

I'm testing models using rspec. Everything was ok when i used only rails standard validation helpers. But when i wrote custom validator(sales_price_less_than_retail) tests started to fail.

Here is the code of the test:

```
it { should validate_presence_of :sales_price }
it { should validate_presence_of :retail_price }
it { should validate_numericality_of :sales_price }
it { should validate_numericality_of :retail_price }
```

Here is the factory:

```
Factory.define :offer_option do |f|
  f.sales_price          rand(21) + 10  # $10-$30
  f.retail_price         { |a| a.sales_price * 2 }
end
```

When i run the test i get such errors:

Failures:

1) OfferOption

```
Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :sales_price }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/offer_option.rb:38:in `sales_price_less_than_retail'
 # ./spec/models/offer_option_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) OfferOption

```
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :retail_price }
 ArgumentError:
   comparison of BigDecimal with nil failed
 # ./app/models/offer_option.rb:38:in `>='
 # ./app/models/offer_option.rb:38:in `sales_price_less_than_retail'
 # ./spec/models/offer_option_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I guess everything should be ok because rspec should test validators separately, but it seems that it calls custom validator after calling validates_presence_of in my test.
The problem disappears when i remove custom validator.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that this is because validate_presence_of rspec helper set offer_option.sales_price = nil and then call valid? on offer_option. When calling valid?, it runs all your validations, so your custom validation as well. And then you get this error, cause there is no '>=' method on nil.

if you change sales_price_less_than_retail to:

```
def sales_price_less_than_retail
  return if sales_prices.blank? || retail_price.blank?

  if sales_price >= retail_price
    errors.add(:sales_price, "must be less than retail price.")
  end 
end
```

Then it should works.

Comment: I don't think this would work if the sales_price or retail_price were set to empty strings from a form input. You would need to check if they were present. I will usually return from the method if the conditions aren't met rather than having a long chain of conditionals.    
`return if sales_price.blank? || retail_price.blank?`

Comment: True, I need to improve my example

Comment: Thanks for this! Although this seems like a hack, is there something fundamentaly wrong with how we are writing out test?